# How to make this string into an Array - String has space and so do values

Tags: php, arrays

```
transactionid=67002 msisdn=12136018066 destination_msisdn=12136018066 country=Canada countryid=701 operator=1Canada operatorid=2350 reference_operator= originating_currency=CAD destination_currency=CAD product_requested=3 actual_product_sent=3 wholesale_price=3.61 retail_price=3.70 balance=9.96 sms_sent=no sms= cid1= cid2= cid3= pin_based=yes pin_option_1=key in : *105* (top-up code) # (press call button) pin_option_2=Click the WIND icon on your phone pin_option_3=to access the menu, and top up in a few quick steps pin_value=3 pin_code=9973 44700 7583 pin_ivr= pin_serial=5500000008 pin_validity=365 authentication_key=1455826552 error_code=0 error_txt=Transaction Good
```

When we make this into an array we dont want to lose values like `pin_code` that has spaces within the data like the delimiter of the string which is also a space. Here is my code so far:

```
$parsed = preg_split('/\s+/',$string); 
$page_is = array_shift($parsed_url); 
$getVars = array(); 
foreach($parsed as $argument) { 
    list($variable,$value) = explode("=",$argument); $getVars[$variable] = $value; 
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at the problem? Please paste your code so far.

Comment: $parsed = preg_split('/\s+/',$string);
$page_is = array_shift($parsed_url);

$getVars = array();
foreach($parsed as $argument)
{
list($variable,$value) = explode("=",$argument);
$getVars[$variable] = $value;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach worked for me:

```
$str        = "transactionid=67002 msisdn=12136018066 destination_msisdn=12136018066 country=Canada countryid=701 operator=1Canada operatorid=2350 reference_operator= originating_currency=CAD destination_currency=CAD product_requested=3 actual_product_sent=3 wholesale_price=3.61 retail_price=3.70 balance=9.96 sms_sent=no sms= cid1= cid2= cid3= pin_based=yes pin_option_1=key in : *105* (top-up code) # (press call button) pin_option_2=Click the WIND icon on your phone pin_option_3=to access the menu, and top up in a few quick steps pin_value=3 pin_code=9973 44700 7583 pin_ivr= pin_serial=5500000008 pin_validity=365 authentication_key=1455826552 error_code=0 error_txt=Transaction Good" ;
$parts      = explode('=', $str);
$key        = array_shift($parts);
$last_value = array_pop($parts);

foreach($parts as $part) {
    preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $part, $match);
    $next_key    = $match[0];
    $value       = str_replace($next_key, '', $part);
    $array[$key] = $value;
    $key         = $next_key;
}

$array[$key] = $last_value;
$array       = array_map('trim', $array);

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

fun with regular expressions:

```
$regex = '/(\w+)=((?:.(?!\w+=))+)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

and if you have php 5.5 or greater you can place this cherry on top (bottom)

```
$values = array_combine(array_column($matches, 1), array_column($matches, 2));
var_cump($values);
```